# moving picturebox elements

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Can anyone tell me how can I move elements that are in the picturebox?

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

For example i have the elements 4 4 1 3 (the first row). How could I switch elements 1 and 3 ?

Here's the code:

```
        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (numbers == null) 
            {
                return;
            }
            int xMaxCoordinate = numbers.GetLength(0);
            int yMaxCoordinate = numbers.GetLength(1);

            int xVieniba = pictureBox1.Width / xMaxCoordinate; 
            int yVieniba = pictureBox1.Height / yMaxCoordinate;

            Pen _pen = new Pen(Color.White, 1F);
            Font fonts = new Font("Times New Roman", 10);
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(numbers[i, j].ToString(), fonts, brush, i * xVieniba, j * yVieniba); 
                }
            }
            for (int i = yVieniba; i < pictureBox1.Height; i += yVieniba)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(_pen, 0, i, pictureBox1.Width, i);
            }
            for (int i = xVieniba; i < pictureBox1.Width; i += xVieniba)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(_pen, i, 0, i, pictureBox1.Height);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think you need at least a simple object which will hold the `X-axis`, the `Y-axis` and the number value of each square and choose some proper data structure, maybe array will do it, which holds position for each element. Then you can use another data structure, I think queue will do it, where you can hold clicks (each two clicks mean changing two squares, then empty the queue or the data structure by choice).

Comment: Well, my thinking was that I'd have to create a new array everytime i change anything, if that's what you thought and if I understood you correctly. But I still have no clue how to do it. I guess I'll just do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that paints the picturebox grid accepting a 2 dimensional array, to store the coordinates and the value of any red square.
In order to change a number (or switch two numbers) I'd simply modify the array and repaint the picturebox

**Edit: some easier way to do it?**

If you just want to play around and create a simple game I think it'd be easier to create as many `PictureBox` as you need, with `BackgroundColor` red and a `Tag` property set to its number (3, 4, 4, 1 etc etc).

Then put them close to each other creating and filling a `TableLayoutPanel` and then paint the `Tag` property of each `PictureBox` in its corner.

In alternative, you could also use a `Label`, with `Autosize = False` and specific size and just write the number there, it's even easier.

After that you can easily handle the `click event` on each pictureBox/Label, get the values from the Tag/Text property and maybe change the background color on click. On the 2th click you redraw the number in both your pictureboxes/labels and reset the color to red, giving the impression that they were switched

Comment: Hm, but i'll need to use the mouse to move them. For example, if i'll click on 1 and then on 3, they'll switch places.

Comment: It might be more complex than you think... there's no magic way to do that. start doing it "manually", without clicks. just write the coordinates you want to switch in 2 different textboxes and press a button to see if it works. At least it's what I'd start with. Then you can move on with detecting the mouse click, get the value under the mouse position etc etc

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot. I'll post here either it works or not.

Comment: Gave it some thoughts and I don't really know how to even select a specific region at the picturebox. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: You're right, that's not easy to do, check the edited answer. Hope it helps, good luck with your game